# Mybatis string value insert into oracle CLOB

Tags: java, oracle, performance, mybatis

I'm trying to insert list of records into oracle database by using mybatis orm.
Below exception throws while insert into database.

> Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Query I have written to insert the data.

```
<insert id="insertCusHistoryData" parameterType="com.dpworld.tos.admin.model.CusHistory">   
      INSERT INTO 
         CUS_ACTION_HISTORY_T(SEQ_NO, GLOBAL_ID, REQUEST_ID, CUS_ACTION_CODE, CUS_REQUEST_TIME, ENTITY_TYPE, ENTITY_KEY, PARENT_ENTITY_KEY,
             DELTA_CHANGE, TOTAL_PROCESSING_TIME, TOTAL_SERVER_PROCESSING_TIME, USER_AN, UPDATE_MODE, TOTAL_TIME)
            select  A.*  from(
     <foreach collection="cusHistory" item="history" separator="UNION ALL" >  
        SELECT 
                #{history.sequenceNo} as SEQ_NO,
                #{history.globalId} as GLOBAL_ID,
                #{history.requestId} as REQUEST_ID,
                #{history.cusActionCode} as CUS_ACTION_CODE,
                #{history.cusRequestTime} as CUS_REQUEST_TIME,
                #{history.entityType} as ENTITY_TYPE,
                #{history.entityKey} as ENTITY_KEY,
                #{history.parentEntityKey} as PARENT_ENTITY_KEY,
                #{history.deltaChange, jdbcType=CLOB},
                #{history.totalProcessingTime} as TOTAL_PROCESSING_TIME,
                #{history.totalServerProcessingTime} as TOTAL_SERVER_PROCESSING_TIME,
                #{history.userAn} as USER_AN,
                #{history.updateMode} as UPDATE_MODE,
                #{history.totalTime} as TOTAL_TIME
            FROM DUAL 
    </foreach>)A
```

But when I modify insertion code like below it inserts property, but it takes around 23 seconds tom complete the job.

```
BEGIN
     <foreach collection="cusHistory" item="history" separator="" > 
         INSERT INTO 
         CUS_ACTION_HISTORY_T(SEQ_NO, GLOBAL_ID, REQUEST_ID, CUS_ACTION_CODE, CUS_REQUEST_TIME, ENTITY_TYPE, ENTITY_KEY, PARENT_ENTITY_KEY,
            DELTA_CHANGE, TOTAL_PROCESSING_TIME, TOTAL_SERVER_PROCESSING_TIME, USER_AN, UPDATE_MODE, TOTAL_TIME)
         VALUES(
                #{history.sequenceNo},
                #{history.globalId},
                #{history.requestId},
                #{history.cusActionCode},
                #{history.cusRequestTime},
                #{history.entityType},
                #{history.entityKey},
                #{history.parentEntityKey},
                #{history.deltaChange, jdbcType=CLOB},
                #{history.totalProcessingTime},
                #{history.totalServerProcessingTime},
                #{history.userAn},
                #{history.updateMode},
                #{history.totalTime});
    </foreach>
      END;
```

I have tried by removing the CLOB column from the first and second query, first query took around 8 seconds and second query took around 20 seconds to complete, huge performance issue comes in this case.

Please advice.